# How to obtain FunctionImport HttpMethod in OData V3?

Tags: odata, metadata, http-method

I have an OData V3 service where some of the FunctionImport elements have HTTP method set to POST, e.g.:

<FunctionImport Name="DeleteFilesetsPartsIndices" m:HttpMethod="POST">

This is a valid setting for OData V3 operations. But IEdmFunctionImport interface in Microsoft.Data.Edm doesn't expose HttpMethod value. I first thought that I can use instead a property IsSideEffecting, but it looks like functions that use GET method also can be marked as side-effecting, so it's not the same thing. Then it's not apparent to me how to identify which HTTP method should be used to execute an OData V3 operation if IEdmFunctionImport (or other EDM interfaces) doesn't expose its verb. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Are you using Web API OData V3? if yes, I am sorry that it doesn't support function, although it uses FunctionImport. It only uses it to take the action role. Hope what I am saying is clear.

Comment: No I am not using Web API, and the server part is OK, I can use functions both via GET and POST. My problem is that I want to programmatically detect which HTTP verb to use, and it's not exposed by IEdmFunctionImport interface.

Comment: Any updates on this? I too noticed that there doesn't seem to be a way to make ODataLib (?) emit the attribute.